# hibernate last record id

Tags: hibernate, record

I wanted to change staus from "inserting" to "Finish" when data insertion is complete usinmg hibernate.
I have tables as USER and another DETAILS.They have relation as one-to-many.
Initially I am inserting USER values as first name,status. Then his DETAILS values as phno.

while I inserting into USER table I want to keep status as 'inserting'  when I enter values in  DETAILS I want to change status to "Finish".

I am doing as ,

```
//Parent table
USER user = new USER();
user.setFirstName("A");
user.setStatus("inserting");
session.save(user);
//Child table
DETAILS details = new DETAILS();
details.setPhone("12345");  

details.setManyToOne("user");
user.getdetailSet().add(details);
session.save(details);
```

How can I achive to change status to "Finish" from "inserting" after above code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Err,

```
user.setStatus("Finish");
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: actually I wanted something like .I m inserting multiple records in DETAILS table.That time status should be "inserting" in USER table.When insertion is complete I want to make it 'Finish' in USER table. I have read something like I need to capture last insert id in USER table and once I got it I will update status.  Is this possible ?

Comment: Why would you need the last inserted ID in the User table. You have a User entity, and it's attached to the session. Every changeyou make to this user will be saved in the database by Hibernate. Have you read the Hibernate reference manual and understood how it worked?